# Periodic sync of data using Llama

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, sync, 3g, automation, llama

Is it possible to set an Event using Llama, to repeat each hour that switches on the 3G connection, syncs data and then turns off the 3G connection again.

I would like to use this during work hours to check email etc without having to complete the task manually throughout the day.

Comment: I'd like to understand the background to your question. Why don't you just leave 3G on and set your email client &c. to check every hour?

Comment: I have limited 3G data. Even if change the sync rate for email apps etc, there some apps such as Plume which ignore this and update continually regardless of the setting. I thought Llama could control the connectivity. Switching it on and off peridocially.

Comment: I don't use Llama, so I'll let someone else answer that, but you may find it doesn't help much, because all the apps which wanted to update will update at once as soon as you connect to Internet. Try it anyway, and let us know how much it helps.

Comment: Llama does have repetitive functionality but I am unable to get the desired result!

Comment: Usually it should be enough to periodically switch data connection (and background sync) on/off. As for Plume (ignores pretty anything) I'd recommend taking a look at [Greenify](http://www.appbrain.com/app/greenify/com.oasisfeng.greenify), which can automatically "freeze" it while it's not in foreground. Side-Effect: enhanced battery life! I just "greenified" Plume last night. Usually, at this time my battery is down to ~80% – today it's still at 96%, which I'd call a difference :)

Comment: Can Greenify be installed on 2.3.5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I programmed Llama to do exactly that.

You'll need two events:

- 3G auto on
- 3G auto off

and one Llama variable:

- auto3G

**Event 1 (3G auto on)**

- when airplane mode is disabled *[prevents the system to work if airplane mode is enabled]*
- when mobile data is not connected *[this ensures there will always be a break of 60 minutes after each (manual) data or wifi connection]*
- when your phone disconnects from any wifi network *[same as above]*
- when variable 'auto3G' **does not** have a value of 1 *[new variables don't have values; this also ensures that data connections are not interrupted when activated manually]*
- delay for 60 minutes *[change this to your needs, e.g. 15 minutes]*
- enable mobile data
- set Llama variable 'auto3G' to 1 *[so the system knows data connection was activated automatically]*

**Event 2 (3G auto off)**

- when mobile data has connected *[lets te system wait until data connection is established]*
- when 'auto3G' has a value of 1 *[only if data connection was activated automatically]*
- delay for 45 seconds *[change this to your needs and speed of synchronization]*
- disable mobile data
- set Llama variable 'auto3G' to 0 *[system reset]*

this should cover your needs ;)

Answer (score 0):

As Izzy pointed out in the comments, Greenify might be what you are looking for. It includes an option (I suspect that this is only available for paid version users) to consolidate all app's sync actions. If several apps have sync tasks, Greenify will "collect" all those tasks and then wake the phone periodically and run all those tasks at once. This is exactly what you are looking for, no?